# Python map to read multiple .txt files

Tags: python, python-2.7, text

I program in R and but in this project I'm working with python.

In R I learnt that I should avoid `for loops` to `apply` method to get a faster running time (and simpler code writing), but I'm having trouble to do this in python.

I have an array with the text files names like this:

`texts = ["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"]`

I'm reading the file like this (notice that the codec is required):

```
f = codecs.open(texts[0], "r", "ISO-8859-1").read()
```

What I want is the "a.txt", "b.txt" and "c.txt" to be read, and what I tried was:

```
f = map(codecs.open("r", "ISO-8859-1").read(), texts)
```

But it didn't work, and a `for loop` is unfeasible because I have lots of files and folders.

I worked around this code and the errors I get are:

> ValueError: mode string must begin with one of 'r', 'w', 'a' or 'U',
>   not 'ISO-8859-1'

or

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'r'

Comment: `map` is just a prettified `for` loop.

Comment: Don't be afraid to use `for` loops in python. Unlike in R, it the common way of doing things.

Comment: `f = map(lambda x: codecs.open(x, "r", "ISO-8859-1").read(), texts)`. You need to actually feed a file name to the open function.

Comment: I'd use [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.hook_encoded), though I'd be interested to know how having lots of files/folders makes a for loop any more unfeasible than your desired approach...

Comment: Thanks guys. Why is my question downvoted? Any tips to improve or is downvoted because I was assuming a wrong concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops in Python are much faster than they are in R and are the easier and preferred method in many situations.

The way I would approach this problem would be with a for loop and a `with open(...)` loop.

```
for text in texts:
    with open(text, 'r') as file: # 'r' is for read mode
        print(file.read())
```

It's not clear what you want to do with the output, but you would modify the code inside the loop depending on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not necessary to avoid loops in python. But if you want to do it you have a choice:

- map
- list comprehensions
- generators

map example (like already @Abdou wrote in the comments):

```
open_fn = lambda text: codecs.open(text, "r", "ISO-8859-1").read()
f = map(open_fn, texts)
```

In this case, you get a map object and you could iterate over it.

list comprehension:

```
open_fn = lambda text: codecs.open(text, "r", "ISO-8859-1").read()
files = [open_fn(text) for text in texts]
```

You will get a list with data.

Generators

```
open_fn = lambda text: codecs.open(text, "r", "ISO-8859-1").read()
files = (open_fn(text) for text in texts)
```

You will get a generator object.

Also, you should keep in mind that you can iterate only one time over a map and generator. And as many as you want on the list.

Also, you can read more info [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-better-to-use-list-comprehensions-or-map-with-a-lambda-function-when-manipulating-elements-in-a-list)